# ФетИш или фЕтиш?

Tags: фонетика

Чаще можно услышать слово "фЕтиш", но где-то мне попалась информация, что правильно все-таки "фетИш". Так ли это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово произошло от французского "fetiche" и правильным будет только ударение на последнем слоге, [фетИш](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%25F4%25E5%25F2%25E8%25F8)